# Acumos installation and /var/lib/docker size

Tags: acumos

After doing the Acumos oneclick_deploy.sh install and running Acumos for a day I noticed that the /var/lib/docker folder contains 14GB of data. Is this normal? Will it increase? Can it be cleaned up in some way (in case it is junk)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The directory /var/lib/docker has all the Docker data. The "containers" subdirectory stores all the Docker images that the all-in-one installer downloaded and started to run the Acumos instance.  That's easily 14GB of images.  So yes this is normal.  Please note that as you on-board models the number of docker images and the size of that folder will grow further.

Also see: https://docs.docker.com/get-started/